# GPU Tridiagonal Solver (CUDA) : Non base 2 tridiagonal system

Tags: cuda, gpu

Is there any working tridiagonal solver for non base 2 matrix (for example matrix as such: 500X500)?
The algorithm at https://code.google.com/p/tridiagonalsolvers/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Ftridiagonalsolvers deals only with base 2. 
Is there any difficultly in implementing such solver for non base 2 matrices?

Comment: What do you mean by "The algorithm that was offered by Nvidia"? Can you give a link or a specific function that you are referring to?

Comment: Sure - https://code.google.com/p/tridiagonalsolvers/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Ftridiagonalsolvers

Comment: I don't see any indication that code was "offered by Nvidia".

Comment: Indeed this was my mistake. It was suggested by Yao Zhang in https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.idav.ucdavis.edu%2Ffunc%2Freturn_pdf%3Fpub_id%3D978&ei=MqLnU46eK6Sp7AbQuYHgAg&usg=AFQjCNHpNGaSIe9OSRU6OQcQ0Z4Vc1o2lQ&sig2=QXJg4OBWbvMIhWjw5omACQ&bvm=bv.72676100,d.ZGU&cad=rja

Comment: Do you have any insights? Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cuSparse library can sovle tridiagonal systems of arbitrary length.

The two functions you want to look at are:

1. cusparsegtsv(): http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/#cusparse-lt-t-gt-gtsv
2. cusparsegtsv_nopivot(): http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/#cusparse-lt-t-gt-gtsv_nopivot

There is also a batched tridiagonal solver.

You'll get best performance when the matrix side-length is a power-of-two, but you may not lose a lot of performance for non power-of-two matrices, especially if they're slightly below a power of two.